# SQL Server 2008 - Multiple Updates WIth Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am looking for a way to speed up the SQL, because I think I am not doing it efficiently, though it is working but very slow when there are more records.

I am using ASP/VBScript, but this is SQL Update issue.

I have a loop `FOR, NEXT,` capturing the submission form and process to capture the `SortNum` submitted.

```
for x = 1 to request.form.count
    ' -- Some where here, I captured the SortNum that associated with RecID
     SortNum = TheCapturedRowNum
     TheRecID = TheCapturedRecID

     sql_UpdateSortNum = "Update Table1 SET SortNum = '"& SortNum &"' where RecID = '"& TheRecID "'"
     conn.execute(sql_UpdateSortNum)
Next
```

Currently, it is working, but the more record (over 50 records), it will get more slower. I guess it is a bad way to loop through and keep executing the update query. Is there a way to speed up the update, like stored and update one time? please note that `SortNum` value is NOT the (x) of FOR loop.

Any advice would be appreciated,

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ Send all rows in "request.form" to a stored procedure ( as a parameter having [XML data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748087/passing-parameters-as-xml-to-a-stored-procedure)  or as [table value parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) then use [UPDATE FROM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server) statement.

This way will avoid back-and-forth calls to database.

2/ If you don't want to modify too much your code, and if you have a reasonable number of rows to update, you can join more update statements (let's say in batches having about 50 update statements) and send them together to DB:

```
"Update Table1 SET SortNum =...;Update Table1 SET SortNum =...;Update...;"
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand. So, I still need to loop through, but instead of using the Update in my code, I should create a stored procedure that take 2 parameters (RecID, SortNum), then using Update SQL in my store procedure, correct? Basically, I still need to loop through the store procedure and feed the 2 parameters to the update store procedure? Any example, would be apprecidated!

Comment: @milacay You should loop through your records and create one string in XML format. Then, send that string to a stored procedure that accepts an XML parameter.

Comment: @milacay: UPDATE FROM allows you to update more rows in a single UPDATE statement.

Comment: I haven't done UPDATE FROM before, but I will research about it. By any chance, do you have any reference links for that XML and UPDATE FROM sample? Thanks for helping.

Comment: @milacay: follow the link in my answer.

Comment: @SQLhint.com, I tried the option# you suggested, building a string for multiple UPDATE statements, seperated by (;), but it is not working from page execution, CONN.Execute(SQLString).  But when I copied/pasted the SQLString in the SQL Server Manager, and run, it works. Any suggestion?

Comment: No Error, but it works now. Somehow execute the SQLString (with bunch of update statements) in the Transaction didn't work.  I moved it out of the Transaction, and it works.  Not sure why